# different method of running pytorch on gpu

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

See the code block below (the source of the code can be found [here](https://github.com/cshwhale/Med3D), also you don't need to read the whole block, I will explain and highlight the important part)

```
def train(data_loader, model, optimizer, scheduler, total_epochs, save_interval, save_folder, sets):
    # settings
    batches_per_epoch = len(data_loader) # 
    log.info('{} epochs in total, {} batches per epoch'.format(total_epochs, batches_per_epoch))
    loss_seg = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=-1) 

    print("Current setting is:")
    print(sets)
    print("\n\n")     
    if not sets.no_cuda:
        loss_seg = loss_seg.cuda()
    
    # change model in training mode, enable batch normalization etc
    model.train()
    
    # record train time 
    train_time_sp = time.time()
    
    # loop to train the model
    for epoch in range(total_epochs):
        log.info('Start epoch {}'.format(epoch))
        
        scheduler.step()
        log.info('lr = {}'.format(scheduler.get_lr()))
        
        for batch_id, batch_data in enumerate(data_loader):
            # getting data batch
            batch_id_sp = epoch * batches_per_epoch
            volumes, label_masks = batch_data

            if not sets.no_cuda: 
                volumes = volumes.cuda()

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            out_masks = model(volumes)
            # resize label
            [n, _, d, h, w] = out_masks.shape
            new_label_masks = np.zeros([n, d, h, w])
            for label_id in range(n):
                label_mask = label_masks[label_id]
                [ori_c, ori_d, ori_h, ori_w] = label_mask.shape 
                label_mask = np.reshape(label_mask, [ori_d, ori_h, ori_w])
                scale = [d*1.0/ori_d, h*1.0/ori_h, w*1.0/ori_w]
                label_mask = ndimage.interpolation.zoom(label_mask, scale, order=0)
                new_label_masks[label_id] = label_mask

            new_label_masks = torch.tensor(new_label_masks).to(torch.int64)
            if not sets.no_cuda:
                new_label_masks = new_label_masks.cuda()

            # calculating loss
            loss_value_seg = loss_seg(out_masks, new_label_masks)
            loss = loss_value_seg
            loss.backward()                
            optimizer.step()

            avg_batch_time = (time.time() - train_time_sp) / (1 + batch_id_sp)
            log.info(
                    'Batch: {}-{} ({}), loss = {:.3f}, loss_seg = {:.3f}, avg_batch_time = {:.3f}'\
                    .format(epoch, batch_id, batch_id_sp, loss.item(), loss_value_seg.item(), avg_batch_time))
          
            if not sets.ci_test:
                # save model
                if batch_id == 0 and batch_id_sp != 0 and batch_id_sp % save_interval == 0:
                #if batch_id_sp != 0 and batch_id_sp % save_interval == 0:
                    model_save_path = '{}_epoch_{}_batch_{}.pth.tar'.format(save_folder, epoch, batch_id)
                    model_save_dir = os.path.dirname(model_save_path)
                    if not os.path.exists(model_save_dir):
                        os.makedirs(model_save_dir)
                    
                    log.info('Save checkpoints: epoch = {}, batch_id = {}'.format(epoch, batch_id)) 
                    torch.save({
                                'ecpoch': epoch,
                                'batch_id': batch_id,
                                'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
                                'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()},
                                model_save_path)
                            
    print('Finished training')            
    if sets.ci_test:
        exit()
```

This is a customised training function, the author achieve GPU running by using code `loss_seg = loss_seg.cuda()` where `loss_seg` is a instance of `torch.optim.SGD`. This part confused me, because according to the official documentation in [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html), I only need to move my model and my input data to gpu is enough. I want to know why the author who write the code below also move the optimizer to the gpu and more details about running pytorch on gpu.

Answer (score 1):

In general, in order to harness the full power of GPUs, every *stateful* `Module` should be sent to a `cuda` device before the forward step. A stateful `Module` has an internal state, e.g. `Parameter` (weights).

This is not usually the case of `Loss`, which, in general, applies just a functional that has been already implemented for `cuda` devices.

In conclusion, if the loss is stateful, then it makes sense to send it to a `cuda` device, otherwise, it is not necessary.

Have also a look at [this question](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/move-the-loss-function-to-gpu/20060) in the PyTorch forum.